# Search/change URL in Page Viewer Web part (WSS 3.0)

Tags: search, wss-3.0, page-viewer-web-part

I have a Project Web Access site collection that contains at least 100 pages (out of several thousand) where Page Viewer web parts are targeted to a URL that is no longer valid. The URLs have changed from a pattern like http://randomsite101.site.com/whatever to http://randomsite/whatever (don't ask why we don't deal with this by DNS).

I could change the URLs manually if needed but the larger problem is that the target URL for a page viewer is apparently not indexed for search. Any clever ideas for finding these instances?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it would work in your case, but one way to access and modify Web Part information is to use SharePoint Web Services. Take a look at the following methods: GetWebPartPage, GetWebPart2, SaveWebPart2.

Here is the link for Office 12:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms774747(v=office.12).aspx